# Fetch all the students on the basis of ascending marks

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, php-7, query

This query fetches all the student name and there ids on basis of topics but i want to get these result on basis of ascending marks ... i.e select `student_name` and `ids` where  `student_topic` = `topic` but fetch them in the ascending order of there `topic_marks`
how and where should i add `->orderby()` or `->order()`

```
  $myTable = $this->_connection->getTableName('Students');
        $sql = $this->_connection->select()->from(
            ["tn" => $myTable], array('student_name', 'student_id')
        )->where('student_topic = ?', $topic);
        $result = $this->_connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $result;
```

Comment: `->order('topic_marks ASC')` try it or `->order('topic_marks', 'asc');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
$myTable = $this->_connection->getTableName('Students');
    $sql = $this->_connection->select()
        ->from(
        ["tn" => $myTable], array('student_name', 'student_id'))
        ->where('student_topic = ?', $topic)
        ->order ('topic_marks','asc');
    $result = $this->_connection->fetchAll($sql);
    return $result;
```